# vi undo "n-th" previous change

Tags: vi

What I've seen so far is that I can only revert to a previous state but not selectively undo, say, only a change which was done prior to the last two changes.  Example, I'm editing a 50 line file and delete line 20 then insert text on line 25 followed by inserting a line at line 30.  Now I want to only undo the line 20 deletion, is that possible?  I've seen references to mundo and undotree plugins but, before I invest in learning them, I'd like to know that what I want to do is possible with hopefully an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could install [the undotree addon](https://vimawesome.com/plugin/undotree-vim) for vim